# Writing a function to split a string

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a function to split a string (not use strtok) to learn how it works. I've come up with the following so far:

```
char ** split_string(char * string, char sep) {
    // Allow single separators only for now

    // get length of the split string array
    int array_length = 0;
    char c;

    for (int i=0; (c=string[i]) != 0; i++)
        if (c == sep) array_length ++;

    // allocate the array
    char * array[array_length + 1];
    array[array_length] = '\0';

    // add the strings to the array
    for (int i=0, word=0; (c=string[i]) != 0;) {
        if (c == sep) {
            i=0;
            word ++;
        } else {
            array[i][word] = c;
            i++;
        }
    }

    return array;

}
```

This is my first time working with a pointer to a pointer (a list of strings), so I'm a bit unclear how to do this, as you can probably tell from the above function.

How would this be properly done? Specifically, is the return type correct? How would you add the `\0` to the end of the array?

Comment: Well, but you will be disappointed since you have declared the array of pointer local to the function such that when `split_string` returns, your `char * array[array_length + 1];` becomes invalid.... Allocate dynamically if you want an array of pointer so that the storage is not on the function-stack, but on the heap and will survive the function return. Option2 - if just splitting in two, you can simply return a pointer to an address within the original string where the second part of the string will begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the one mistake you are making is not allocating space for the words to be copied. You must explicitly allocate space for the words in the destination array before copying. Following program achieves what's intended. To know the number of words, declare `array_length` to be a global variable, so that you can use that in the function where `split_string` was called.

```
int array_length=0;
char** split_string(char* str, char sep){

    for(int i = 0;str[i] != '\0';++i){
        if(str[i] == sep) ++array_length;

    char** str_arr = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * (array_length+1));
    for(int i=0, j, k = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++k){     // k is used to index the destination array for the extracted word
        for(j = i; str[j] != sep && str[j] != '\0'; ++j);   // from the current character, find the position of the next separator
        str_arr[k] = (char*)malloc((j-i+2)*sizeof(char));    // Allocate as many chars in the heap and make str_arr[k] pointer point to it
        strncpy(str_arr[k], str+i, j-i);       // copy the word to the allocated space
        i=j+1;              // move the array iterator to the next non-sep character
    }
    return str_arr;
}
```

If you don't want to use `malloc` explicitly, you can also use library function `strndup` which takes the pointer to the start character of the  source string and number of characters to be copied as input and **does the memory allocation, copies the word and returns the pointer to the allocated space**. so two of the lines in the function

```
str_arr[k] = (char*)malloc((j-i+2)*sizeof(char));    // Allocate as many chars in the heap and make str_arr[k] pointer point to it
strncpy(str_arr[k], str+i, j-i);
```

can be replaced by a single line as-

```
str_arr[k] = strndup(str+i, j-i);
```

But I would recommend using the first method as a beginner for better understanding and debugging.

Note: The above program works only for single delimiter between words, if there is an occurrence of multiple consecutive delimiters between words, you will have to tweak the program a bit in order to get it working.

Comment: You shouldn't cast the return value of functions that return `void*` like `malloc` in the `C` language. Any cast can hide a bug and casting a `void*` to a specific pointer is not necessary in `C`.