# Appending words to an array based on a separator

Tags: c, string, split

I am trying to break up the sentence "once upon a time" into an array of words. I am doing this via a `for` loop, detecting three conditions:

- It's the end of the loop (add the `\0` and break);
- It's the separator character (add the `\0` and advance to the next word)
- It's anything else (add the character)

Here is what I have now:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char ** split_string(char * string, char sep) {
    // Allow single separators only for now

    // get length of the split string array
    int i, c, array_length = 0;

    for (int i=0; (c=string[i]) != 0; i++)
        if (c == sep) array_length ++;

    // allocate the array
    char ** array_of_words = malloc(array_length + 1);
    char word[100];

    for (int i=0, char_num=0, word_num=0;; i++) {

        c = string[i];

        // if a newline add the word and break
        if (c == '\0') {
            word[char_num] = '\0';
            array_of_words[word_num] = word;
            break;
        }

        // if the separator, add a NUL, increment the word_num, and reset the character counter
        if (c == sep) {
            word[char_num] = '\0';
            array_of_words[word_num] = word;
            word_num ++;
            char_num = 0;
        }

        // otherwise, just add the character in the string and increment the character counter
        else {
            word[char_num] = c;
            char_num ++;
        }
    }

    return array_of_words;

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    char * input_string = "Once upon a time";

    // separate the string into a list of tokens separated by the separator
    char ** array_of_words;
    array_of_words = split_string(input_string, ' ');
    printf("The array of words is: ");

    // how to get the size of this array? sizeof(array_of_words) / sizeof(array_of_words[0]) gives 1?!
    for (int i=0; i < 4 ;i++) 
        printf("%s[sep]%d", array_of_words[i], i);

    return 0;

}
```

However, instead of printing "once", "upon", "a", "time" at the end, it's printing "time", "time", "time", "time".

Where is the mistake in my code that is causing this?

Here is a working example of the code: https://onlinegdb.com/S1ss6a4Ur

Comment: You only have storage for one word. You need to allocate storage for each word. (Exactly the same mistake as in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57864726/253056)).

Comment: What's `array_length`? What's `sep`? What's `string`? What's `c`? Where is your `main` function?

Comment: @PaulR I see -- I just came to that conclusion too (after about an hour of getting the same thing over and over again...). How would I be able to create a new variable that has a different memory address every time I get a new "word" ?

Comment: @Blaze updated with a full example

Comment: `array_length` is still undefined in `main`. Please provide the actual code that you compiled.

Comment: @Blaze sorry I've updated this again. Here: https://onlinegdb.com/S1ss6a4Ur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for each word, not just for one. `char word[100];` only puts aside memory for one word, and once it goes out of scope, the memory is invalid. Instead, you could allocate the memory dynamically:

```
char* word = malloc(100);
```

And then, when you found a separator, allocate memory for a new word:

```
if (c == sep) {
    word[char_num] = '\0';
    array_of_words[word_num] = word;
    word = malloc(100);
```

Also, this here is incorrect:

```
char ** array_of_words = malloc(array_length + 1);
```

You want enough memory for all the `char` pointers, but you only allocate `1` byte per pointer. Instead, do this:

```
char ** array_of_words = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(array_length + 1));
```

---

The `sizeof(array_of_words) / sizeof(array_of_words[0])` works to calculate the amount of elements when `array_of_words` is an array, because then its size is known at compile time (barring VLAs). It's just a pointer though, so it doesn't work as `sizeof(array_of_words)` will give you the pointer size. Instead, you'll have to calculate the size on your own. You already do so in the `split_string` function, so you just need to get that `array_of_words` out to the `main` function. There are multiple ways of doing this:

- Have it be a global variable
- Pass an `int*` to the function via which you can write the value to a variable in `main` (this is sometimes called an "out parameter")
- Return it along with the other pointer you're returning by wrapping them up in a `struct`
- Don't pass it at all and recalculate it

The global variable solution is the most simple for this small program, just put the `int array_length = 0;` before the `split_string` instead of having it inside it.

---

Last but not least, since we used `malloc` to allocate memory, we should `free` it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {
        printf("%s[sep]%d", array_of_words[i], i);
        free(array_of_words[i]); // free each word
    }
    free(array_of_words); // free the array holding the pointers to the words
```

Comment: I can't tell you how helpful this answer was for me. As soon as I read it and took some time to review it, I was able to understand what I was doing wrong and make a working function (on my own). Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Is strtok not suitable?

```cpp
   char str[] = "once upon a time";
   const char delim[] = " ";

   char* word = strtok(str, delim);
   while(word != NULL)
   {
      printf("%s\n", word);
      word = strtok(NULL, delim);
   }
```